# RHEL 6.3 Mysql Install

Tags: mysql, redhat, yum

I am attempting to install mysql on a server. It's a fresh install of RHEL 6.3. Yet, when I run 'yum install mysql mysql-server, I get the following messages.

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Setting up Install Process
No package mysql available.
No package mysql-server available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Could someone tell my if I am missing something here as the above message only indicates to me that the repo being used doesn't have what I am wanting to install in it. If I am just not using a proper repo, perhaps you could direct me accordingly. I am using EPEL.

```
epel      Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64          7,676
rpmfusion-free-updates      RPM Fusion for EL 6 - Free - Updates    162
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates   RPM Fusion for EL 6 - Nonfree - Updates  22
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a [bug in RHEL 5.8 and 6.3](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/solutions/78153) ([mirror](http://mcvictech.blogspot.com/2012/06/yum-error-unable-to-read-consumer.html)). You should contact Red Hat for a solution if the one provided does not work for you.

Edit: Since the other answer was actually correct, and whoever it was deleted it... You also must have an active Red Hat subscription for the machine.

Comment: Is it really necessary to have a subscription just to use a repository?

Comment: @Skittles Yes, it's required.  Have you registered this system with `rhn_register`?

Comment: I just got the credentials from my network guy. Looks like it took them after running rhn_activate. Thanks, to both of you.